# How exactly do I install an epson wf-2630 printer onto my new ubuntu studio OS?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I've read that there's some sort of package that has to be installed before I can even get the "linux version" of setup file or drivers, but nothing I see tells greenhorns where to go do this stuff at.  Where is my "source file" list for example, and how do I access it?  Can someone give me step by step instructions that don't assume I know where things are and includes all the steps, not just part of the process??  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1: Boot into Ubuntu

Step 2: Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Step 3: Login as user with administrator permissions.

```
sudo -i
```

Step 4: Install the previous packages needed:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall firefox cups lsb gdebi sane simple-scan
```

Step 5: Navigate to these sites and download the packages for 32 or 64 bits according to their distribution:

```
firefox    
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=ES&CN2=&DSCMI=43797&DSCCHK=b349e6644abd5c99e22fee221df756e1130c0725
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.4-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
or
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.4-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html
https://download2.ebz.epson.net/iscan/general/deb/x86/iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz
https://download2.ebz.epson.net/iscan/general/deb/x64/iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
```

Step 6: Untar the file .deb.tar.gz

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar zxf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x86.deb.tar.gz
or
tar zxf iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
```

Step 7: Install the files.deb whith gdebi:

```
Click the right mouse button. Select install with gdebi.
```

Step 7: Run Firefox and select your printer:

```
firefox
Enter the address: localhost:631
```